# Branch is behind main

Tags: git

I'm currently just messing around with git and cant figure out how to set a branch to a newer commit. My current git history looks like this:

```
6be8bf1 (HEAD, main)
701c50a
95cfe6b (origin/mybranch)
1a82bd5
...
```

How can I edit my history to look like below?

```
6be8bf1 (HEAD, main, origin/mybranch)
701c50a
95cfe6b
1a82bd5
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(assuming your local is in sync with origin i.e. you've run `git fetch` already):

`git checkout mybranch`

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mybranch mybranch`

`git merge main`

Verify that your setup looks like this at this stage:

```
6be8bf1 (HEAD, main, mybranch)
701c50a
95cfe6b
1a82bd5
```

`git push origin mybranch`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can you explain a bit about what --set-upstream-to does?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html You use it when `you already have a local branch and want to set it to a remote branch you just pulled down`

Comment: well.. I think you're exaggerating a little here. In addition, the --set-upstream step can be done when pushing by setting the same flag there or just giving the short option `-u`

Answer (score 22):

If your branch is behind by main then do:

```sh
git checkout main (you are switching your branch to main)
git pull 
git checkout yourBranch (switch back to your branch)
git merge main
```

After merging it, check if there is a conflict or not.
If there is NO CONFLICT then:

```
git push
```

If there is a conflict then fix your file(s), then:

```
git add yourFile(s)
git commit -m 'updating my branch'
git push
```