# Deploying Gatsby site to GitHub Pages (process hangs?)

Tags: github, npm, deployment, gatsby, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my Gatsby site to GitHub pages. I've followed all the instructions in this tutorial: [Gatsby GHPages Tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/). Setting up my gh-pages branch and adding the path prefix and script deploy command.

However, when I run `npm run deploy` everything goes fine at first but eventually, the process seems to hang at `info Done Building in 22 sec`. I've also attached a screenshot of my logs after running the command. Please let me know if there is any more information I should provide to help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

[image: npm run deploy log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the deploy command is.. 
`"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",`

Move the `README.md` from the root directory or delete it.

Create an `index.html` file and add `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=public/index.html">` to it. [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919200/github-pages-only-showing-readme-file).

Execute `npm run deploy` which should result in "Published" at EOF.

Change the branch from `master` to `gh-pages` in the repo settings.

Comment: Just tried that. So the full command was now: `gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public -b master` and have the same issue still. And my pathPrefix matches the repo name.

Comment: I apologize for getting back with you so late. Does the master branch already exist? "Note: to select master or gh-pages as your publishing source, you must have the branch present in your repository." Also, post the link of the repository and I will try to publish a version of it myself.

Comment: No worries, appreciate the help. I've tried everything at this [link](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-modern-library-boilerplate/issues/15) and here's the repo [link](https://github.com/willjrowe/IR-Plan-Site). At this point I just have the `master` branch because I'm just trying to get anything to work haha

Comment: What I would really like is some output from the hanging process but I don't quite understand how to set NODE_DEBUG see [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#debugging)

Comment: Hey @WillRowe I was able to get it to publish but it is only displaying the README. Let me fix it really quick and then I will get back with you.

Comment: @WillRowe I updated the answer and created a pull request to your repo. Let me know if you have any other issues - @ me if so, I do not have notifications enabled otherwise.

Comment: @WillRowe any updates on this? I'm currently dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my particular case what solved the issue was:

- Globally installing `gh-pages` with `yarn global add gh-pages`
- Updating my deploy script to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public -b gh-pages"
  },
```

- If you have a `dev` branch make sure that you are on it. [Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484321/4781067) with the `master` if necessary and deploy from inside the `dev`. `git push origin dev`
- Create an `index.html` file at the root of the project and add `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=public/index.html">` as aforementioned by [@A Webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12954021/a-webb).

It ended up looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=public/index.html">
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Please keep in mind that once you run `npm run deploy` it may look like it's stuck but it takes some time, at least in my case it did. You'll know it's finished once it says "Published".

[image: Gatsby published]

Just for the sake of testing I'd wait around 30 minutes depending on the size of your website.